# Maintain provenance across Corda business networks

Tags: corda

Within one business network (Business Network A), a notary provides validation and signing off on the transaction proposed by N number of participants.

In the situation where this asset needs to be transferred from one business network (Business Network A) to another (Business Network B), how will the provenance work already completed on the Business Network A be maintained, handled while working in Business Network B?

when there is a transfer of assets from one network to another.
i.e. Morgtage Home Loan Cordapp --->  needs asset transferred to Legal Lending Cordapp

it's not completely clear how the notaries will be setup, and the level of privacy and/or data isolation that will be able to be maintained between notaries on different collaborative Business networks.

Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

[One requirement for a compatibility zone](https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/attachment/277/0/Blockchain%20Compatibility%20-%20A%20Corda%20Explainer%200.5.pdf) is that all the nodes in the compatibility zone are able to transact for any purpose at any time using any application using any vault data. Among other things, this implies that:

- The notaries in the compatibility zone are not associated with any individual business network(s). Each notary is a notary for the entire compatibility zone
- All nodes in the compatibility zone are required to trust all the notaries in the compatibility zone

When you want to move a state to a new notary, you use the built-in `NotaryChangeFlow` to repoint the state to the new notary:

```
val newStateAndRef = subFlow(NotaryChangeFlow(originalState, newNotary))
```

If the new notary is validating, it will request the entire transaction chain from the caller of `NotaryChangeFlow`.